# PHOENIX - Could not find or load main class $PHOENIX_OPTS

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am trying to execute a  sqlline-thin.py file on terminal , but I get an exception in windows command prompt

**Error: Could not find or load main class $PHOENIX_OPTS**

In Linux- Its Executed properly. But, There is no value assigned $PHOENIX_OPTS.

Let me know, What is $PHOENIX_OPTS environment Value?

> set the environment variables are HADOOP_HOME, HBASE_HOME, PYTHON_HOME.

Comment: You can set it on the commandline, but in general it's set in the queryserver.py

Comment: yes. I asked usage of property and default value. Which property should be specify the Max and Min java Heap size. Let me know, default java heap size.

Comment: Is there fix for this error?